# how to set rowspan table use foreach schema in PHP code

Tags: php, html

now im doing PHP code for display report using table with foreach. but i still confuse how to set rowspan using foreach. i want the display like this image

[image]

if i do it manualy, the HTML code should be like this.

```
<table> 
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th >IMAGE</th>
        <th >Name</th>
        <th >Accessories</th>
        <th >Qty</th>
        <th >Action</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td  rowspan="2"><img src=""></td>
        <td  rowspan="2">John</td>
        <td >Cable</td>
        <td >1</td>
        <td  rowspan="2">Delete</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td >standart</td>
        <td >3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td  rowspan="3"><img src=""></td>
        <td  rowspan="3">james</td>
        <td >screen</td>
        <td >1</td>
        <td  rowspan="3">Delete</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td >CPU</td>
        <td >1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td >memory</td>
        <td >2</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

but how do i implement that using foreach. here is what i implement it.

```
<table width="100%" >
    <thead>
        <tr>
          <th >Image</th>
          <th >Name</th>
          <th >Accessories</th>
          <th >Qty</th>
          <th >Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach ($reports as $report)
        <tr>
            <td class="text-center"><img src="{{ $report->image }}"></td>
            <td class="text-center">{{ $report->name }}</td>
            <td class="text-center">{{ $report->accessories }}</td>
            <td class="text-center">{{ $report->qty }}</td>
            <td class="text-center"><button>delete</button></td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

i want rowspan number on "image" and row "name" Adjust the number of "accessories" data. please help.

Comment: i dont see any problem in your code. JUst add rowspan as in html.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new array where you group all the rows with the same name. Then you can get the length of the nested `accessories` array so you'll know the correct value of `rowspan`

```
$grouped_reports = [];
$last_name = null;
$group = null;
foreach ($reports as $report) {
    if ($report->name != $last_name) {
        if ($group) {
            $grouped_reports[] = $group;
        }
        $group = ['name' => $report->name, 'image' => $report->image, 'accessories' = []];
    }
    $group['accessories'][] = ['name' => $report->accessories, 'qty' => $report->qty];
}
// Add last group to $grouped_reports
if ($group) {
    $grouped_reports[] = $group;
}

...
<tbody>
@foreach ($grouped_reports as $report) {
    @$rowspan = count($report['accessories']);
    <tr>
        <td class="text-center" rowspan="{{ $rowspan }}"><img src="{{ $report['image'] }}"></td>
        <td class="text-center" rowspan="{{ $rowspan }}">{{ $report['name'] }}</td>
        <td class="text-center">{{ $report['accessories'][0]['name'] }}</td>
        <td class="text-center">{{ $report['accessories'][0]['qty'] }}</td>
        <td class="text-center" rowspan="{{ $rowspan }}"><button>delete</button></td>
    </tr>
    @for ($i = 1; $i < $rowspan; $i++) {
    <tr>
        <td class="text-center">{{ $report['accessories'][$i]['name'] }}</td>
        <td class="text-center">{{ $report['accessories'][$i]['qty'] }}</td>
    </tr>
    @endfor
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

Comment: i revision my queston. please take a look. i want number rowspan on  "image" and  "name" is adjust the total number of  "accessories"

Comment: How does the output relate to what's in `$reports`?

Comment: That's not an answer. How is it supposed to know how many rows each element of `$reports` should use? Please show the contents of `$reports` that produces the output example.

Comment: Are there multiple elements of `$reports` with the same `$report->name`, and they need to be grouped together?

Comment: yes.. with the same  $reports-name in each row. not use group